# Vectorizing multiple gaussian calculations

Tags: matlab, vectorization, gaussian

I am attempting to vectorize some of my code that adds the intensity of many Gaussian distributions over an image. I currently loop over the function 'gaussIt2D' for each Gaussian, which is vectorized for a single 2D gaussian:

```
windowSize=10;
imSize=[512,512];
%pointsR is an nx2 array of coordinates [x1,y1;x2,y2;...;xn,yn]
pointsR=rand(100,2)*511+1;
%sigmaR is the standard deviation of the gaussian being created
sigmaR = 1;

outputImage=zeros(imSize);

for n=1:size(pointsR,1)
    rangeX = floor(pointsR(n,1)-windowSize):ceil(pointsR(n,1)+ windowSize);
    rangeX = rangeX(rangeX > 0 & rangeX <= imSize(1));
    rangeY = floor(pointsR(n,2)-windowSize):ceil(pointsR(n,2)+windowSize);
    rangeY = rangeY(rangeY > 0 & rangeY <= imSize(2));
    outputImage(rangeX,rangeY) = outputImage(rangeX,rangeY)+gaussIt2D(rangeX(1),rangeX(end),rangeY(1),rangeY(end),[sigmaR,pointsR(n,1),pointsR(n,2)]);
end

function [result] = gaussIt2D(xInit,xFinal,yInit,yFinal,sigma,xCenter,yCenter)
    %Returns gaussian intenisty values for the region defined by [xInit:xFinal,yInit:yFinal] using the gaussian properties sigma,centerX,centerY

    [gridX,gridY]=ndgrid(xInit:xFinal,yInit:yFinal);

    result=exp( -( (gridX-xCenter).^2 + (gridY-yCenter).^2 ) ./ (2*sigma.^2) );

end
```

I am trying to further vectorize this process by allowing the gaussIt2D function to accept a vector of x and y values and a vector of x and y centers and do all of them together. My thought process so far has been to try to stack the grids and replicate the centers and do the element-wise gaussian calculations. For (a simplified) example if:

```
xInits = [1,2,3];
xFinals = [2,3,4];
xCenters = [1.2,2.8,3.1];
yInits = [1,2,3];
yFinals = [2,3,4];
yCenters = [1.5,2.4,3.6];
```

Then I was thinking to create grids and centers following the form:

```
gridX = [1,2
         1,2
         2,3
         2,3
         3,4
         3,4]

xCenters = [1.2,1.2
            1.2,1.2
            2.8,2.8
            2.8,2.8
            3.1,3.1
            3.1,3.1]
```

This could then be used in the same gaussian equation used in the original function. However, generating these arrays is tripping me up. What I have right now is:

```
function [result]=gaussIt2DVectorized(xInits,xFinals,yInits,yFinals,sigmas,xCenters,yCenters)
    %Incomplete
    %Returns gaussian intenisty values for the region defined by 
    %[xInit:xFinal,yInit:yFinal] using the values array:[sigma,centerX,centerY]
    [gridX,gridY]=arrayfun('ndgrid',xInits:xFinals,yInits:yFinals);
    xCenters = repelem(xCenters,numel(xInits(1):xFinals(1)), numel(yInits(1):yFinals(1)));
    yCenters = repelem(yCenters,numel(xInits(1):xFinals(1)), numel(yInits(1):yFinals(1)));

    result=exp( -( (gridX-xCenters).^2 + (gridY-yCenters).^2 ) ./ (2*sigmas^2) );

end
```

This doesn't actually work though, and the I also anticipate difficulty accounting for ranges (ie xInit:xFinal) of different lengths.

Any help, tips, or alternate methods would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In your example code above. When you write sdWindow*sigmaR, is this the same as windowSize?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I had changed sdWindow*sigmaR (in my original code) to windowSize for this example to make it clearer. Apparently I missed one, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot be sure that the grids will all be the same size, it's probably best to store them in a cell array rather than stacking them in a matrix. With cells arrays, you can still run your calculation without looping using `cellfun`.

For example:

```
function [result] = gaussIt2D_better(xInits,xFinals,yInits,yFinals,sigmas,xCenters,yCenters)
    [gridsX, gridsY] = arrayfun(@(x) ndgrid(xInits(x):xFinals(x), yInits(x):yFinals(x)),1:length(xInits),'UniformOutput',0);
    f=@(gridX, gridY, xCenter, yCenter, sigma) exp( -( (gridX-xCenter).^2 + (gridY-yCenter).^2 ) ./ (2*sigma.^2) );
    result=cellfun(f, gridsX, gridsY, num2cell(xCenters), num2cell(yCenters), num2cell(sigmas), 'UniformOutput',0);
end
```

Note that in this example, the value returned is a cell array with the same length as the input vectors, one result for each.

Comment: Oddly enough, while this is a vectorized method, it actually takes longer to execute than the original gaussIt2D function. (100,000 points, 3% longer exectution time). While it doesn't take all that much longer, I was somewhat surprised as it isn't looping anymore.

Comment: This is to be expected. In general, while using arrayfun and cellfun has the advantage of shorter/neater code, it isn't as efficient as looping. This is addressed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/304894). If you're after performance, I would suggest using a loop. As vectorizing is not saving you time in this case. Of course, if you know that all the grids are the same size, then you could actually take advantage of vectorizing for performance as well by storing them in a 3D matrix. Still I doubt the performance will be much better than a loop in this case.